# Gremlin - query properties from multiple entities

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have `product` vertex and `is_duplicate_with` edge established between two `product` vertices. So the data model is like: `product(id=1) -> is_duplicate_with(created_by=abc) -> product(id=2)`

How to write a Gremlin query to get product `id` from the source product, `created_by` value from the is_duplicate_with edge and product `id` from the target product? In this sample, I want to get id=1, created_by=abc, id=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `path` step for this.

```
g.V('1').outE('is_duplicate_with').inV().hasId('2').
  path().
    by(id).
    by('created_by')
```

Or if you don't know the IDs up front

```
g.V().outE('is_duplicate_with').inV().
  path().
    by(id).
    by('created_by')
```

If you really need the key/value pairs in the result you can do something like this:

```
g.V().outE('is_duplicate_with').inV().
  path().
    by(project('id').by(id)).
    by(valueMap('created_by'))
```